# Anycubic firmware update fail and screen blinks or update firmware never ends

Tags: firmware

I spend many hours tonight with a friend figuring out what's happening and solving my Anycubic Vyper firmware update. I had various issues :

- While updating with the current version (2.4.5 as of today) I had many issues from no file update (the firmware update program display a list of file with 000 values on their right showing that nothing is processed and the checksum at the end having done nothing
- Partial update leading to corrupted graphical interface freezing or blinking with locked actions/menus.
- Never-ending update process blocking in "ICL" files (waited more than 40 minutes)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by searching clues on the internet (a [Reddit topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnycubicVyper/comments/qssia2/anycubic_vyper_245_firmware_update_and_can_no/)) that lead me to the following configuration that worked for me (update completed, with sound at the end and all is functional in about 1 minute)

- Format MicroSD card in **FAT32**, with allocation size of **4096 bytes**
- Use a small SD card (I failed many times with a 16GB one). It worked **with a 8GB one** for me. (this tip is not said in the Reddit topic but made the job for me)

Comment: I recently had an issue with a failing 16Gb card and found that the issue was that I had more than one partition on the card, just in case that helps somebody.